# This edit was intended to address the author of the post

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

Reviewing my profile today I noticed [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15912540) that I made a couple weeks ago got rejected. I'm wondering if perhaps I should have included a link to the Big Query docs or something like that. I'm sure I've seen plenty of other posts where newer syntax is included alongside the older syntax in an update, so I don't think it's that.

It's clear that the original author was using the Legacy syntax since he responded saying that it worked, but I'm sure others might run into the same issue I did and the question does not specify the syntax. My company uses the StandardSQL syntax for all of our Big Query queries, so I needed to do additional research to find the StandardSQL syntax.

Am I wrong in my thinking, or were 3 of 5 reviewers a bit overzealous in their rejections?

Comment: Relevant part of the rejection reason bolded: "This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. __It should have been written as a comment or an answer__."  Offering a modern, updated answer is better.

Comment: First rule of edits: Do not put words in the OP's mouth.  It there was something wrong with the code you added then the OP gets the flack, not you.

Comment: That makes more sense. I initially thought about making it my own answer, but I felt like my addition wasn't fully mine since the OPs answer gave me direction to find what I needed in the docs and helped very much in me reaching my own answer.  But I'll add a separate updated answer instead. Thanks!